# How to get value from a span class with a countdown timer?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I have been playing around with webscraping and basically what I am trying to is to scrape down a timer that is right now that is shown etc in picture below:

[image]

What I want to scrape is the 00 : 14 : 40 : 38 and what it does is that every second it counts down but basically what I wish is that whenever I do a webscrape, Just grab the value that is currently right now.

However I coded this and it gave ma a value of None:

```
bs4 = soup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
test = bs4.find("span",{'class':'countdown-row countdown-amount'})
print(test)
```

[image]

could that be an issue because of the countdown or? Because whenever I do print(bs4) it will not be shown in the print the span class but on the website there is...

Comment: Please provide a link to a website you are scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, So I managed to understand that the data-code was actually a Epoch time which only needed to be converted to a real time! That was the solve!

Comment: Can you please update your question with the URL of the website you are scraping? Someone could post a full answer to your question that might help others one day + you'll see an alternative approach to what you've already solved by yourself.

Comment: How did you convert epoch time to real time?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Timer doesn't exist at the moment when the page is scrapped. You can try to print the whole "mother" div of this span. But I bet that it is initialized by JavaScript, so you need to use some other tools, like Selenium or Scrapy (last one can manage with some JS behaviors, but I am not sure, that it can help with this one), to scrap that.

Comment: Okey, So I managed to understand that the data-code was actually a Epoch time which only needed to be converted to a real time! That was the solve!